# how to read custom property of parent ListView from external delegate?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a ListView and its delegate defined in other qml-file.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        width: 180; height: 200
        property color delegateColor: "green"

        model: listModel
        delegate: ExternalDelegate {}
    }
}
```

ExternalDelegate.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ItemDelegate {

    background: Rectangle {
        color: ListView.view.delegateColor
    }

    Text {
        text: model.name
    }
}
```

Parent ListView has a custom property delegateColor. I need to read this property from the delegate. But if I try to access it by attached property ListView.view it does not work. And I see messages in console:

`qrc:/ExternalDelegate.qml:7: TypeError: Cannot read property 'delegateColor' of null`

How to read custom property of ListView from an external delegate?

I need to set this property in ListView (not in delegate) because I also want to access this property from header, footer and section delegates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it is better that the components do not know what they are used for but rather to expose through properties of the root element, for example an alias of the color of the rectangle can be created, and in the case of the text the ItemDelegate component already has that property.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ItemDelegate {
    id: root
    property alias color: bg.color
    background: Rectangle {
        id: bg
    }
    contentItem: Text {
        text: root.text
    }
}
```

```
delegate: ExternalDelegate {
    text: model.name
    color: ListView.view.delegateColor
}
```

Another solution is to only change the alias for a new property:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ItemDelegate {
    id: root
    property color color : "white"
    background: Rectangle {
        color: root.color
    }
    contentItem: Text {
        text: root.text
    }
}
```